# Processing multiline events from a text file in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am attempting to build a dataflow pipeline to process a text file which contains events that span multiple lines. The dataflow SDK TextIO class assumes each line is a new event.

My plan is to create a new TextReader and register it with the DataPipelineRunner. This new reader will know how to aggregate the multiple lines into a single line.

I am pretty sure that this approach will work but I am wondering if this is the right way to do it or if there is a simpler solution?

The text I am trying to parse is:

```
==============> len:45 pktype:4 mtype:2
SYMBOL: USOCSTIA151632.00
OPEN_INT: 212
PR_OPEN_INTEREST: 212
TIME_STAMP: 04/10/2015 06:30:17:420  val:1428661817
```

The result should be the last 4 lines concatenated together and the first line dropped.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: A couple more questions: 1) do you have many small files, or are your files large? (i.e. do you want to parallelize processing within one file) 2) Would it be correct to say that the beginning of a record in your file can be detected by looking for "==============>" ?

Comment: There are many large (200G+) files that need to be processed. The line starting with "===>" does indicate a new record but I need that line stripped out of the output.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Note that TextReader is an internal implementation detail class, so subclassing it would be highly discouraged and challenging to do properly.

The recommended way to define a new file-based format like yours is to **subclass FileBasedSource** using the [user-defined source API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/sources-and-sinks#creating-sources).

In your case, I would recommend to base your class on the LineIO example from documentation, and wrap the LineReader defined there into your own class which would use LineReader as a helper for reading individual lines, but:

- In [startReading()](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource.FileBasedReader#startReading(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel)) it would skip until the line starting with "====>"
- In [readNextRecord()](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource.FileBasedReader#readNextRecord()) it would read lines until the next "====>" and bundle them into a single record.

Please make sure to carefully read the documentation to FileBasedSource and FileBasedReader: the parallelization mechanism relies on the consistency properties described there, which your format has to satisfy, for ensuring that records are not duplicated or omitted on the boundaries between adjacent processing shards. [XmlSource tests](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/XmlSourceTest.java#L704-755) are a good example of how to unit-test these properties.

Please tell us how it goes and report back with any problems or questions - we are very interested in feedback on this API.

Comment: Yes I quickly discovered that extending TextReader was very difficult. I originally tried subclassing Source but ran into some issues. I will back track and take a second look.

Comment: Where is the "LineIO example"?