# Example of FileBasedSource usage in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Can someone post a simple example of subclassing FileBasedSource? I'm new to Google Dataflow and very inexperienced with Java. My goal is to read files while including line numbers as a key, or to skip lines based on the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of [XMLSource](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/XmlSource.java) is a good starting point for understanding how FileBasedSource works.  You'll likely want something like this for your reader (where readNextLine() reads to the end of a line and updates the offset):

```
protected void startReading(ReadableByteChannel channel) throws IOException {
  if (getCurrentSource().getMode() == FileBasedSource.Mode.SINGLE_FILE_OR_SUBRANGE) {
    // If we are not at the beginning of a line, we should ignore the current line.
    if (getCurrentSource().getStartOffset() > 0) {
      SeekableByteChannel seekChannel = (SeekableByteChannel) channel;
      // Start from one character back and read till we find a new line.
      seekChannel.position(seekChannel.position() - 1);
      nextOffset = seekChannel.position() + readNextLine(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a gist with the complete [LineIO](https://gist.github.com/sammcveety/c6026b2439700651d048) example, which may be simpler than XMLSource.

Comment: Honestly I find the XMLSource example hard to follow since it adds the complexity of XML to the issue of reading files. I have to figure out how to "cut it down". [The answer to this question mentions a "LineIO example from documentation"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29775312/3703989) but I can't find it.

Comment: The LineIO example is currently used for testing and is only visible in a private repo, but I can explore publishing it.

Comment: I posted a gist an amended the answer.