# Reading files from GCS line by line to append line numbers to it using FileBasedReader

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

So, I was trying to read a file from **GCS** line-by-line to append line numbers at the end of the line and later make a PCollection out of it(Basically, the goal is to index a PCollection). Hence I've written this code but gives errors:
Below is the implementation classes of **FileBasedSource** and **FileBasedReader**:

```
private static class LineSource extends FileBasedSource<String> {
public LineSource(String fileOrPattern) {
  super(fileOrPattern);
}
private static class LineReader extends FileBasedSource.FileBasedReader<String> {
  public LineReader(LineSource source) {
  super(source);
  }
}
```

Code I wrote which uses these classes to read file line by line is:

```
try {

          LineSource<String> f = new LineSource(fileName);
          LineReader<String> b = new LineReader(f);
          b.startReading(channel);
          int index = 0;
          while(b.readNextRecord()){
            LOG.info("FileBasedSource: "+b.getCurrent());
            c.output(b.getCurrent()+","+index);
            index++;
          }
          b.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But i get these errors:

```
java:[115,49] ')' expected
[ERROR] flatFileTest.java:[115,57] illegal start of expression
[ERROR] flatFileTest.java:[175,2] reached end of file while parsing
```

I guess startReading() method should be implemented again maybe.
I'm relatively new to Dataflow. Can you please help on this?

Comment: You're missing a close curly brace between the end of LineSource and the beginning of LineReader.

Comment: Yeah, that is fixed. there's some error at line 115

Comment: I highly, highly recommend using an IDE that formats your code for you. It saves a lot of time and makes problems that this much easier to spot quickly.

Comment: Yeah, that was in haste. Anyways no luck with remaining errors though.This line **b.startReading(ReadableByteChannel channel);** is giving out errors

Comment: Am I implementing FileBasedSource and FileBasedReader properly? Can you check once please?

Comment: what are the errors you're getting? You should probably write `b.startReading(channel);`

Comment: "illegal start of expression" on that line. First place, I'm not sure I've implemented this properly, can do you me a favour giving me the code snippet of how to read a file from cloud bucket line-by-line using java for me to use in cloud dataflow to index a PCollection. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, I can't figure out how to use **FileBasedSource** and **FileBasedReader** to read files from cloud storage :\

Comment: This is a regular Java syntax error, rather than an error specific to Cloud Dataflow. As Pablo says, your line that says "b.startReading(ReadableByteChannel channel);" is incorrect - it should be "b.startReading(channel);" - in Java, when calling a function, you do not need to specify the type of its parameters, only the values.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot updating the answer, but i tried that as well. no luck

Comment: @jkff can you provide me with a code snippet to read a file into dataflow using filebasedreader?

Comment: @Bluecrow Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647020/example-of-filebasedsource-usage-in-google-cloud-dataflow ? Also note that if you're reading line numbers, you'll need to implement isSplittable() as false, because if you start reading in the middle of a file, there's no way to tell which line number it is, so you can only read entire files, starting from the beginning.

Comment: @jkff it's a bit difficult for a beginner to understand. Can you guide me on "How to read a file line by line from file in cloud dataflow" ?

Comment: I don't have time to create a working code snippet for you, but if you update your question with a description of your latest attempt based on that answer, and tell me what isn't working, I can help you understand how to fix it.